# Dxdiag showing wrong audio device

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, directx

I am trying to run a game and getting an error which is commonly caused due to audio misconfig. So, I checked my dxdiag and for some reason it's showing audio drivers last updated on 2010 (HDAudio.sys). But I have two up-to-date audio drivers from Cirrus Logic and Nvidia which is confirmed in Device Manager. Also, I have three sound tabs(headphone, speaker and digital audio). Is this normal ?

My dxdiag log: http://pastebin.com/CKafhmQj

Comment: "Driver Name" shows it has the nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: the HDAudio.sys is a Windows driver which is part of the audio stack in Windows. this is fine.

Comment: Anyway to fix the date mismatch in dxdiag audio drivers and device manager audio drivers ?